# Can we bundle multiple spring-boot application as a war and deploy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, war, monolithic

We have multiple boot component as well as different schema for each component. We have a business requirement where we need to deliver everything as a war and has to be deployed as a single application on different machine.
I am trying to go with plugin architecture, so that one(new) aggregator microservice will be prepared where we can add every boot component as a plugin and then use them as a bundle(war) deployable.
By enabling a component with maven plugin we have created two jar one executable jar and another original jar. But how do i add them in to the new aggregator component as a plugin and access the rest layer from each component(plugin).

```
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
            <configuration>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
    <classifier>exec</classifier>
    
</configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Do i need any change in approach/ how do i add a spring-boot jar as a plugin to another project? Any references or sample structure/code would be helpful & thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have really the requirement to create mulitple spring-boot application? 
How about refactoring all thoses modules as single application and then, packaging it as war? (Maybe, you can have a maven multimodule project but with single boot application (i.e one entry point))

Comment: I totally agree and the story is ,it was monolithic before breaking this in to boot 
 components. Now while doing this we have maintainability issue in managing two codebases. Thought of managing everything from one place (i.e from Spring Boot code base as the future is Microservice).Now, customers who has already monolithic war deployed they want the same old war deployment. So, decided to go for this approach adding other component as a plugin and access other rest layers .Need some assistance on this.